# Hibernate updating database structure with new indexes

Tags: database, nhibernate, hibernate, refactoring, indexing

It's well known fact that hibernate work with indexes in a very strange way. It generate them only if you create a database schema from the scratch. But if you try to update the database schema hibernate will ignore new indexes.

My question is, does anybody find a solution how to ask hibernate generate SQL for new indexes during schema update.

**UPDATE:**
I'll disagree with [Stefan Steinegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27343/stefan-steinegger). Index management with hibernate it's a pain. Nice to see that the feature was scheduled for next release (3.5.x) and will be backward compatible to 3.3.x and 3.2.x as well. Details are [here](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1012).

Comment: You certainly can disagree with Stefan, but he's absolutely right. Hibernate schema update only give you the very basics. When it comes to indexes / auxiliary objects (triggers / stored procs / etc...), **altering** columns, constraints and so on it's not going to be of any help. There are appropriate tools for that, Hibernate schema update is not one of them. Сокирою цвяхи не забивають :-)

Comment: Thanx ChssPly76. I appreciate you point of view. But I mostly use SchemaUpdate as a diff tool for comparing existing schema with hibernate one. That's why I need to see what changed since last deployment (e.g. new index was added etc.). Right now SchemaUpdate works great for me except the one case - indexes. I know and evaluate couple of database refactoring tools including below mentioned LiquiBase. Most of them can't provide me a level of flexibility that I expect. I'm looking forward to Liquibase 2.0 hope it will satisfy my appetite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resolved in Hibernate 3.5.0-Beta-2 release. Details are [here](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1012) and [here](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10031&version=10950).

Answer (score 3):

Schema update is not intended to be used in a production environment. It should only be used for developers.

Schema export on the other hand is recommendable to be used in production. Export the schema to get the actual schema definition and use other means to update existing databases. Write your own update scripts or use a designated tool.

Comment: +1. For the "designated tool" in question I highly recommend LiquiBase (http://www.liquibase.org/). It even integrates with Hibernate so the manual step of exporting the schema is unnecessary.